# Cant combine files when mapping a dataframe using fread() and map_df in r

Tags: r, data.table, purrr

I am using fread() from the data.table package with map_df() from purr. I have 10000's of csv files whith 1000's of rows. They are all mostly correct execpt occationally the system started writing the new string before the previous row has finished. So one row out of 100000's has glitched. There is not a pattern to it either.

I understand what the issue is and why mapping doesnt work, but I have no idea how to solve it due to the large numbers of files I have. Finding these odd rows and removing them is not possible manually.

I am not too sure how to create an example through code so have included a link to a [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/d0i4qxp9vngluql/AAA_jtUwAy0OQVwUKc77IS08a?dl=0) folder. There are five csv folders names test1 : test 5. Test 5 has the error in it.

```
data <- fs::dir_ls(path = your_path, recurse = TRUE) %>%
              map_df(~fread(., header = TRUE, fill = TRUE))
```

When mapping the data i get this error message:

```
Error: Can't combine `..1$b` <integer> and `..5$b` <character>.
```

I hope I have made things clear. Please let me know if anymore information is needed.

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your column `b` has differing datatypes. In case of your example data that's because there is a date string in `test5.csv`. One option would be to read your files as a list, convert all or just the problematic columns to a character and then apply `bind_rows` to bind them into one data.frame. Afterwards you could figure out what's wrong with the problematic column(s) and how to deal with the issue.

```
library(data.table)
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

data <- fs::dir_ls(path = "fread_error", recurse = TRUE) %>%
  map(~fread(., header = TRUE, fill = TRUE)) %>% 
  map(~mutate(.x, across("b", as.character))) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach reads the frames into a list, and then for each data.table, it retains only the rows where any extra columns have all NAs. It assumes there is a base number of columns that you expect (in your example this is 5)

```
library(data.table)
rbindlist(lapply(lapply(dir(path="fread_error/",recursive = T,full.names = T), fread), function(x) {
  if(ncol(x)>5) x[rowSums(x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) !is.na(x)), .SDcols = -c(1:5)])==0][,c(1:5)]
  else x
}))
```

Given that you have tens of thousands of files, you might want to do this in parallel; one option is here:

```r
library(data.table)
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)

registerDoParallel(cores=detectCores())

rbindlist(foreach(fname =  dir(path="fread_error/",recursive = T,full.names = T)) %dopar% {
    x=fread(fname)
    if(ncol(x)>5) x[rowSums(x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) !is.na(x)), .SDcols = -c(1:5)])==0][,c(1:5)]
    else x  
})
```

Comment: I think i understand what you are saying. You are correct and i should have a set number of columns. Would there be a way to remove any rows where the columns were > 5 as the rest of the data in that row would be incorrect?

Comment: @S_Gill, I believe that is what my approach does for you.  Notice the `rowSums()` component returns a logical vector, which when applied to `i` in data.table `x` retains only the rows where all of the values in the "extra" columns are NA

Comment: @S_Gill did this work for you? If so, please accept the answer. Thanks

Comment: I cannot get it to work just yet. Needed to add `.packages = "data.table"` to the foreach call.  My data has 233 columns, i am calling 47 of them through select. 
`test <- rbindlist(foreach(fname =  dir(path = paste0(file_path, i), recursive = T, full.names = T), .packages = "data.table") %dopar% {x = fread(fname, select = c(1:47))
    if(ncol(x)>47) x[rowSums(x[, lapply(.SD, function(x) !is.na(x)), .SDcols = -c(1:47)])==0][,c(1:47)]
    else x  
  })`
`Error in { : 
  task 2 failed - "Column number 96 (select[18]) is too large for this table, which only has 89 columns.`

Comment: @S_Gill, I don't think select=c(1:47) is the way to go here, because you need fread to pull in the "extra" unwanted columns generated by glitch. Without these, you can't check for all NAs in those "extra" columns, in order to retain those rows.. the `[,c(1:47)]` at the end of the `if` line will eventually drop those extra columns.